# How to allow my wife to use her own credit card in Apple Store?

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

I have set up family group on iPhones for my wife and daughter. Now they are allowed to purchase by my card only. Is it possible for my wife to use her own card and my daughter not to use any cards at all?

Comment: The workaround is to buy iTunes gift cards and redeem them on the individual account.  The credit balance will be used before it goes to the family organizers credit card.  (As an added bonus around Christmas Costco and Sam's club usually have said cards on sale $100 for $85 or a 15% discount. I buy enough then to last all year.)

Comment: Just noted your not in he USA, so disregard the part about getting them at a discount, but the general workaround will still work for you.

Comment: Nope, and Tyson is dead-on. @Tyson you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Incredible. Why is this so?

Comment: Apple does what Apple does and we don't always understand.  In this case however the logic is likely that the don't want groups of unconnected people forming "family's" to share content.